# Nhibernate 3.0 LINQ: Problem returning to IQueryable (non generic version) - doesn't allow ToList()

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, iqueryable

I am using the latest Nhibernate and i have a linq query to return just 1 column. so I can't use for example IQueryable as there is no entity class - i am returning only 1 column. But return to IQueryable Non Generic version doesn't provide the ToList method

Here is the method

```
    public IQueryable GetCode()
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            var results = (from c in _session.Query<Client>()
                           select new
                           {
                               Group = c.Code
                           }).Distinct();

        }
    }
```

Of course if i do this (see below) i get the ToList method on my IQueryable

```
    public IQueryable<Client> GetCode()
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            var results = (from c in _session.Query<Client>()
                           select c;

        }
    }
```

The problem being is that i need to do DISTINCT and use only 1 column.

Any ideas, i am at a loss

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

When i look at the type that is returned via IQueryable it is

{NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType6>}

and looking under the base class of what is returned i see an exception

Expression type 10005 is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor.

Comment: Why do you wrap a transaction (that just is disposed) around the query? That sounds problematic for several reasons.

Comment: Yes Paco, you are right but that doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the following work?

```
public IQueryable<X> GetCode() // X = the type of Client.Code
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {

        var results = (from c in _session.Query<Client>()
                       select c.Code).Distinct();

    }
}
```

The problem here is not just that you can't call `ToList` on a non-generic `IQueryable`, but that the entire result is untyped, so you cannot read the `Code` property of each element either. (This can be worked around with C# 4's dynamic type, but that's not really what you want here.)

In your case, I don't see why you really need to construct an anonymous type just to return a distinct sequence of `Code` values renamed as `Group`. Returning the field's value should be sufficient.

If you'd need to return *more* than just one column, you should create an explicit type, rather than using an anonymous type, so you can say

```
public IQueryable<ClientGroupAndSomething> GetCode()
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {

        var results = (from c in _session.Query<Client>()
                       select new ClientGroupAndSomething
                       { 
                           Group = c.Code, 
                           ... 
                       }).Distinct();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben! Is there no other way if i want to return more than 1 column?  Must i create a explicit type?

Comment: There are always workarounds, such as using the return type `IQueryable<dynamic>` (C# 4) rather than a plain `IQueryable`. Although I don't know whether NHibernate supports that. And then you're no longer working with (compiler checked) statically typed code. A non-generic `IQueryable` erases the static type information, so you've got a query returning elements of an unknown type. For this reason, anonymous types (`new {...}`) should never escape a method.